# How to create choice field in django model using another model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models first User model and second Organization Model.
Admin will be responsible for adding data in Organization Model.So I have used Foreign key.

```
class Organizaton(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to=    {'is_staff': True})
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and I have a Custom User table where I want to store which user belongs to which Organization:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser): 

    organization_name = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

If I declare CustomUser Class first, then there is an error inside
CustomUser class in organization_name field that says `class Organization is not Found or declared`.

If I declare Organization Model class before CustomUser model class, then I'm getting an error inside the Organization class in created_by field saying `CustomUser class not found or declared`.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `CustomUser` first and change your `ForeignKey` to string like following:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser): 

    organization_name = models.ForeignKey('Organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And it won't depend on declaration order anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = app_name.CustomUser` in your settings file?